# Impact of option "everypage" from scrlayer-scrpage package

Tags: pdftex, koma-script

Can somebody confirm that the option `everypage` is having an impact on how often a layer is been printed during page creation? My understanding was that it's not.

However, in the example below my PDF viewer (Okular Version 0.24.2) the text a little bit bold.

I had this effects before with text that was printed multiple times at the same place.
However, in the paper printed version everything is fine...

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\DeclareNewLayer[%
    foreground,%        Avoid multiple code execution.
    addvoffset=5em,%    Adapt position for better comparisim.
    addhoffset=1in + \oddsidemargin,% ...
    mode=text,%
    everypage,%     <--- Impact?
    contents={%
        Text in 'ExtraLayer'.
    }%
]{ExtraLayer}

\AddLayersToPageStyle{headings}{ExtraLayer}

\begin{document}
    \noindent Text in 'headings'.
\end{document}
```

---

[image: Option activated: Upper text different than lower one]
Option activated: Upper text different than lower one.

---

[image: Option deactivated: Upper and lower text look the same]
Option deactivated: Upper and lower text look the same.

---

I am using `pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)`.

Can someone help? Thanks.

Best regards,

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is a little bug in `scrlayer-scrpage`.

There is no need to use `everypage` for a new new declared layer, because it will be printed on every page if you do not set one of the options `evenpage`, `oddpage`, `floatpage` or `nonfloatpage`.

But `everypage` could be helpful if you modify or clone an existing layer. Then `everypage` should reset the changes done by `evenpage`, `oddpage`, `floatpage` and `nonfloatpage`. But unfortunaly it resets the changes done by `foreground` and `background` too. So the layer in your code is printed twice: in foreground and background.

Workarounds if `everypage` is needed:

- replace `everypage` by `oddorevenpage, floatornonfloatpage`
- change the order of `everypage` and `foreground` to `everypage, foreground`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! By the way: I am using `2016/06/14 v3.21 KOMA-Script`

Comment: This is fixed in the current prerelease (3.22.2500) of  the next KOMA-Script version (3.22). You can get prerelaeases from the [KOMA-Script package repositories](http://www.komascript.de/node/1801).